# I can't create a CalendarView inside a Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, methods, android-activity, fragment

Good afternoon, I'm new to Android Studio development. I'm developing an application where I need to create a Calendar in one of the Fragments.

I'm trying to create a CalendarView in my fragment, but the setContentView methods and others are highlighted in red, what am I doing wrong? Below is the code.

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment  {
    private CalendarView calendarView;

    public CalendarFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_calendar);
        CalendarView calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                                            int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                int mYear = year;
                int mMonth = month;
                int mDay = dayOfMonth;
                String selectedDate = new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1)
                        .append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear)
                        .append(" ").toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually highlighted text in IDE gives some extra info about the problem when you hover on them, isn't that the case with Android Studio(or Problems panel somewhere in the UI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try like this**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
        calendarView = view1.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener((view, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
            int mYear = year;
            int mMonth = month;
            int mDay = dayOfMonth;
            String selectedDate = new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1)
                    .append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear)
                    .append(" ").toString();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), selectedDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });


        return view1;

    }
```

Here you need to get `CalendarView` in `onCreateView` and return `view1` otherwise you get  `java.lang.NullPointerException:` Error Like  `View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);`

Comment: The program highlights LayoutInflater and ViewGroup in red and gives an error, maybe I did something wrong? (added a picture with the code)

Comment: add `@NonNull` like this `@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater`

Comment: Thank you, I figured out what I was wrong about